# How to have a table with very huge data as a data source to Tableau

Tags: sql, datasource, tableau-api, partitioning

I have a situation in which I need to make a table (having  up to 20 million rows) as a data source to Tableau. 
Will Table partitioning work or any other method to try as I must have all the data in this particular table only?
Please assist.

Comment: You can connect a table that large to Tableau. I have used 300 million row Vertica tables before. Take an extract to improve performance.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for the reply here. However, my table is taking around 20 minutes to return the data. So if in this pattern, my extract will take too long to refresh. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Please optimize your extract based on performance checklist is followed and also optimize the extract as much as possible.
https://www.interworks.com/blog/bfair/2015/02/23/tableau-performance-checklist
Or
https://www.interworks.com/sites/default/files/InterWorks%27%20Tableau%20Performance%20Checklist.pdf
OR
http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/extracting_optimize.html
OR
https://docs.powertoolsfortableau.com/best-practices-analyzer/#understanding-the-rules